# C# IsPrime skips a prime number

Tags: c#

I am trying to fasten my isPrime function but when I add a condition that if the number is divisible by 2 just return false instead of doing the whole process to find if the number is prime or not, but when I do this, it skips me a number for example the 6th prime is 13, without the condition if it's divisble by 2 I get 13, but when I add it I get 17.

```
    static bool isPrime(long n)
    {
        bool prime = false;
        int div = 0;

        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return false;
        else

        for (long i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)

        {
            if (n % i == 0)
                div++;
            if (div == 2)
                prime = true;
            else
                prime = false;
        }
        return prime;
    }
```

Comment: This is a code-review kind of thing, but when checking for factors, you only need to check from 1 -> sqrt(n).

Comment: a multi-line if or else block requires braces (not an answer, just good practice)

Comment: You need to check the definition of a prime number again - The number 2 is a prime number, but you skip it when you add the mentioned condition.

Comment: @WimOmbelets: Braces aren't required in this code.  Though the `for` block should be indented and whitespace removed to make it more clear that it's in the `else` block.

Comment: also, you can skip the `if(div==2)` check because you're already doing that with the `%` check

Comment: His code works for me anyways :P Am I missing something?

Comment: Side note: You're making a small improvement in performance by removing even numbers from the calculation.  But a little research on calculating prime numbers can result in *much* more improvement on speed here.

Comment: @WhyCry his code returns false if u checked if 2 is a prime number so he needs to remove it..

Comment: Your `for` loop starts from `1`. You can start with `3`.
Also, consider adding the `break` operator in the false-part of `if (div == 2)` checking the `div >= 3`.

Comment: @Dmitry - he can't add a `break` in there. `div` is counting the number of divisors. If it reaches `2` and *stays* there, then it's prime. However, if `div` is incremented again, the number isn't prime. They could, however, just return false if `div` ever becomes `3` or higher.

Comment: if `n % i == 0` you can break out of the for-loop: it's not prime, no need to check other divisors. (you are never using that `div` in this code)

Comment: Yeah I just checked, just replaced his line:  if (n != 2 && n % 2 == 0) and works like a charm :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My bad, the condition should be modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check for the special case of 2 first, it's even but prime.

As an additional optimization, you can improve the bounds you're looping up to; there's no need to go as high as `n + 1`.

Comment: Something like: `if (input == 2) return true; else if (input == 1 || input % 2 == 0) return false;`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to speed up the solution you can do something like that:

```
static bool isPrime(long n) {
  // all integers less than 1 (1 is included) are not prime
  if (n <= 1)
    return false;

  // Error in your code: 2 is prime, even if other even numbers aren't
  if (n % 2 == 0)
    return (n == 2);

  // there's no need to loop up to n: sqrt(n) is quite enough
  long max = (long) (Math.Sqrt(n) + 0.1);

  // skip even numbers when looping: i +=2
  for (long i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) {
    // the early return the better
    if (n % i == 0)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: + 1 For skipping evens and the use of Sqrt(long) in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n % 2 == 0)
    return (n == 2);
```

Modulus operation is slow in most architectures if you compare it to bit level checking. You can choose to only check the least significant bit of each number and get the answer if it's even or odd number.

Just do a AND operation with 1 and the value. The result tells you if it's even.
Example:

```
100101011101 (the value to check)
000000000001 (bitmask to AND with)
000000000001 (the result after AND, still 1 ---> odd number (true in boolean))
```

So:

```
if(!(value & 1))
{
    //even
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Test your compiler and/or optimizer *first* to see if it already performs this optimization! If not, then go ahead and write the code (but comment it liberally). If it does, skip the effort and maintenance headache.